# jQuery, dynamically count number of elements on a page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count the number of inputs on a page with a particular class.

```
$(".count").click(function(){
  var named = $(this).parent().find("input").eq(1).attr('class');
  var count = $('input[name='+named+']').length;
  alert(count + ' of class ' + named);
});
```

The count always returns a value of zero. Have I set the 'count' variable correctly? If not, how should I do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them by class, you'd need to change this:

```
$('input[name='+named+']')
```

to this:

```
$('input[class='+named+']')
```

or this:

```
$('input.'+named)
```

If the element you get in the first line of the handler has more than one class, you'll need to change it from this:

```
var named = $(this).parent().find("input").eq(1).attr('class');
```

to this:

```
var named = $(this).parent().find("input").eq(1).attr('class').split(/\s+/).join('.');
```

so that you end up with:

```
someClass.anotherClass
```

Then use this one:

```
$('input.'+named)
```

Comment: oh man, silly. yes, that is it. thank you. I think it is time for a break.